# XHR requests not functioning when applying site bindings

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, bindings

I use Windows 2012 Server R2, IIS 8.5, and I have a problem. On localhost, no matter the port I choose, my XHR requests in my code function perfectly. However, when I apply a binding, such as applying a host header to port 80, I can access the site, but the XHR request does not appear when I observe the network in developer's tools. Why is this, and how can I fix this?

Note: In my hosts file, I have written the static IP and the host header used above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple and I hadn't realized it. Turns out all I had to do was alter the security settings on my local intranet and that's all it took for me to allow the XHR requests to function. Thank you everyone!